# How can I authenticate users with server-side data using Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js

In passport.js, you would normally sign a user up using post data from one of your routes and it would look something like this:

```
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash: true,
    }));
```

But let's say all of the user data is already on the server, in an array. How can I sign the user up using passport without having to get the data with GET or POST, since the data is already on the server?

To specify why, I'm using express, socket.io, and passport.js, and the reason I can't have a traditional signup form that does all the work for you is because I'm pulling the majority of the user data from an API, and it would not be secure if I were to send this data to the client and then post it. All help is appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: You may have to dig around in the Passport internals. The way it's set up by default is to use the session to manage identity. Over socket.io you'll need another equivalent mechanism, some kind of state per connection.

Comment: @tadman the goal is to take the data from socket.io and send it to passport. the fact that I'm using socket.io should be irrelevant anyway, because all that matters is that the data is on the server, not from post data. I'm just hoping there's a way to take data like say username, email, id, password, that's in an array on the server, and send it to passport to authenticate.

Comment: how do you know who's who? When I first connect to the socket, how do you identify me to log me correctly?

Comment: we're using an API from a game. the user types in their username and region on the game, we have a special method to verify that they own that account, then they type their email and password and sign up. the problem is, I need to save their info from the API as well as their email and password all together. I can't send their user info from the API to the client because then they'll be allowed to go into the files and change it before they submit it. So the bottom line is, I have all the user data in an array on the server, how do I send it to passport for authentication? @yBrodsky

Comment: How about this: https://pastebin.com/SZRv0N96

Comment: As a way of bootstrapping this you might use an AJAX call to establish the session, conventional HTTP, and then send the session identifier over the socket.io connection to establish identity.

Comment: @yBrodsky it's for a signup not for a login.

Comment: sorry, misread.

Comment: @yBrodsky how would i do it for signup?

Comment: Actually, since all the applications I've made are private, I have never had to deal with signup in a node app. =/ But I am guessing the process would be similar. Signup must get the data from a post = req.body